# How do I copy an encrypted AMI from one aws account to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

Currently I am using Packer to create a custom AMI and I would like to share it to multiple aws accounts for our deployment pipeline.

Since I have "encrypt_boot": true, I get this error:
`Errors validating build 'amazon-ebs'. 1 error(s) occurred:
 * Cannot share AMI encrypted with default KMS key`

Would anyone know how I can share an encrypted AMI to multiple AWS accounts?

Comment: Are you using the default KMS or a customer managed KMS?

Comment: You can only do this with customer managed keys https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/share-encrypted-amis-across-accounts-to-launch-instances-in-a-single-step/

Comment: I'm currently using the default KMS. Will have to do some reading on CMKs and would that work with Packer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people mentioned you will have to use a `CMK` to be able encrypt and share snapshots with your other accounts.

You specify the key in the Packer configuration with [kms_key_id](https://packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#kms_key_id) and provide a list of target account IDs that are allowed to use the snapshots with [snapshot_users](https://packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#snapshot_users). You can then use [packer-post-processor-ami-copy](https://github.com/martinbaillie/packer-post-processor-ami-copy) to copy the AMI into other accounts.

Answer (score 3):

You can do using the AWS Please go through the blog
[How to share encrypted AMIs across accounts to launch encrypted EC2 instances | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-share-encrypted-amis-across-accounts-to-launch-encrypted-ec2-instances/).

Comment: Is there a way I can do it through Packer?

Comment: @KrunalRami when you post an answer to a question, here, you need to actually post the answer to the question, not simply link to an off-site resource. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/211183